# Capturador Global de excepciones

Tags: c#, excepciones

He implementado en mis aplicaciones un capturador global de excepciones.

En program he puesto estas 2 sentencias:

```
     Application.ThreadException +=
            new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
     Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

     static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        ExceptionUtility eu = new ExceptionUtility();
        eu.LogException((Exception)e.ExceptionObject, "");
        FormLogViewer log = new FormLogViewer();
        log.lwFlag = true;
        log.Show();
    }

    static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        ExceptionUtility eu = new ExceptionUtility();
        eu.LogException(e.Exception, "");
        FormLogViewer log = new FormLogViewer();
        log.lwFlag = true;
        log.Show();
    }

    public void LogException(Exception e, string source)
    {
        error err = new error();
        err.amxFecha = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        err.amxUsuario = datosPublicos.awNomUsuario;
        err.nmxUsuario = datosPublicos.nwNumeroUsuario;
        if (e.InnerException != null)
        {
            err.amxType = e.InnerException.GetType().ToString();
            err.amxMessage = e.InnerException.Message;
            err.amxSource = e.InnerException.Source;
            if (e.InnerException.StackTrace != null)
            {
                err.mmxTrace = e.InnerException.StackTrace;
            }
            else
            {
                err.mmxTrace = " ";
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            err.amxType = " ";
            err.amxMessage = " ";
            err.amxSource = " ";
            err.mmxTrace = " ";
        }
        err.amxType1 = e.GetType().ToString();
        err.amxMessage1 = e.Message;
        if (source == "")
        {
            err.amxSource1 = " ";
        }
        else
        {
            err.amxSource1 = source;
        }
        if (e.StackTrace != null)
        {
            err.mmxTrace1 = e.StackTrace;
        }
        else
        {
            err.mmxTrace1 = " ";
        }
        if (err.mmxTrace != " ")
        {
            err.amxUbicacion = extraigoLineaError(err.mmxTrace);
        }
        else
        {
            err.amxUbicacion = extraigoLineaError(err.mmxTrace1);
        }
    }
    
    public string extraigoLineaError(string awTrace)
    {
        string awRetorno = "";
        string[] aLineas1 = awTrace.Split(new Char[] { '\\' });
        for (int i = 0; i < aLineas1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (aLineas1[i].Contains("línea"))
            {
                awRetorno = aLineas1[i].Substring(aLineas1[i].LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                string[] aLineas2 = awRetorno.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
                awRetorno = aLineas2[0] + " " + aLineas2[1];
                break;
            }
        }
        return awRetorno;
    }

     public static void muestroError(Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionUtility eu = new ExceptionUtility();
        eu.LogException(ex, "");
        FormLogViewer log = new FormLogViewer();
        log.lwFlag = true;
        log.Show();
    }
```

En `ExceptionUtility` lo que hago es grabar toda la información del error para luego poder visualizarla, todo queda registrado para facilitar el encontrar y corregir el error.

Si en algún lugar del programa hago captura de errores con `try...catch` en vez de hacer un `messagebox`, lo que hago es ejecutar el método `MuestroError()`.

Todo esto junto con otras medidas me permitía que mis programas al momento de estar a la venta no necesitaran mantenimiento.

Antiguamente en *Clipper* yo además capturaba una foto de la pantalla y la última tecla apretada por el usuario.

Hoy además debería almacenar donde se hizo clic con el *mouse* en caso de que esta haya sido la última acción antes del error.

He hecho diversos intentos para capturar la foto pero sin éxito.

Preguntas:

1. ¿Es posible capturar la foto de la ventana activa, la última tecla presionada o el último click del mouse (sobre que componente se hizo) ?
2. ¿Como se haría esto?
3. ¿Es posible mejorar lo que estoy haciendo, tal vez agregando algún otra linea para capturar excepciones?

Comment: Si lo que busca es mejorar aspectos del código, le sugiero generar la pregunta en [Code Review Stack Exchange.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). 
Saludos

Comment: @Mauricio, el mejorar el código es la 3er pregunta, pero lo importante para mí es poder capturar la foto y la última tecla o click del mouse

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar una imagen de un formulario, lo puedes hacer así:

```
public static Image GetFormImage(Form p_Form)
{
    Rectangle bounds = p_Form.Bounds;

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
    p_Form.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, bounds);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Si lo que se desea es la captura de pantalla, el siguiente método ya sin parámetros hace una captura de la pantalla completa. Sería así:

```
public static Image GetScreenImage()
{
   // Dimensión de pantalla
   Rectangle sizeDesktop = Screen.GetBounds(this.ClientRectangle);

   // creamos un bitmap para copiar el contenido de la pantalla
   Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(sizeDesktop.Width, sizeDesktop.Height);
   // creamos el objeto gráfico para dibujar en el bitmap 
   Graphics bmpCanvas = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
   // copiamos lo que hay en pantalla al bitmap
   bmpCanvas.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
   // liberamos recursos                            
   bmpCanvas.Flush();

   // Devolvemos la imagen capturada
   return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: el error se puede producir en cualquier momento y no sabria que formulario es el activo en ese momento y quisiera capturar lo que la persona esta ingresando, por eso lo que preferiria seria una foto de la pantalla de la computadora.

Comment: He ampliado la respuesta con otro método para la captura de la pantalla.

Comment: en el método estático me dice que no puedo poner this.ClientRectangle, le saque la propiedad static y si bien tengo using System.Windows.Forms; me da error en la primer linea del metodo.

Comment: this es tu formulario principal.

Comment: No obstante también puedes poner Rectangle sizeDesktop = Screen.GetBounds(new Rectangle(0,0,100,100));